# Row MainAxisSize.min breaks when wrap with Align

Tags: flutter

Below code renders as

[image]

but if I uncomment  `// alignment: Alignment.center`,
it renders as

[image]

Why `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` constraint breaks by adding alignment on the parent container (which may internally wraps in Align widget).
my intention is to `ChipText` only takes the minimal width needed, unless wrap in expanded.

```
class ChipText extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipText({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    this.bgColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final Color? bgColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 24.0,
        maxHeight: 32.0,
        minWidth: 24,
      ),
      // alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: bgColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
            child: Icon(icon),
          ),
          Text(text),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('hello'),
                ChipText(
                  text: 'add',
                  icon: Icons.ac_unit,
                  bgColor: Colors.black26,
                ),
                ChipText(
                  text: 'add',
                  icon: Icons.ac_unit,
                  bgColor: Colors.black26,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: ChipText(
              text: 'add',
              icon: Icons.ac_unit,
              bgColor: Colors.black26,
            ),
          ),
          ChipText(
            text: 'add',
            icon: Icons.ac_unit,
            bgColor: Colors.black26,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```